# How to handle empty objects with jQuery .each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, each

I'm running into trouble an array in an array is empty.

I got two arrays which I push into a new one, so I can use jQuery .each() with the new array. The new array can have different states:

contain empty arrays:

```
nextEvent = [[ ], [ ]]
```

contain two full arrays which contain one object each:

```
nextEvent = [[object], [object]]
```

or contain one full array with one object:

```
nextEvent = [[object], [ ]]
nextEvent = [[ ], [object]]
```

Now I'm trying to use .each() on `nextEvent`, in order to append the existing objects data to an element.

So far i got a function which looks like this:

```
$.each(nextEvent, function(i, n){           
    if (nextFeedingTime || nextShowTime){                       
        var time = n[0].Time.toString();                
        //...
        if (nextFeedingTime && nextShowTime){
            if (n[0].Kategorie === "Fütterung"){
                appendFeeding();                    
            } else {                        
                appendShow();               
            }
        } else if (nextFeedingTime && !nextShowTime){                   
            appendFeeding();
        } else if (!nextFeedingTime && nextShowTime){
            appendShow();
        }
    } else {
        //...
   }    
});
```

Note: `nextFeedingTime` and `nextShowTime` are the arrays i originally pushed into `nextEvent`

This function is working, but as soon as one array is empty I get an `n[0] is undefined` error. Any Ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this:

```
if(n[0] !== undefined)
```

check for the undefined check and proceed.

Comment: Then the function is not working in case of `nextEvent = [[ ], [object]]`, because the first `n[0]` is not defined. I still need it to use the second object.

Comment: @kvothe that will be handled by the next iteration of `$.each`

Comment: @KevinB you are right, found the mistake somewhere else in my code. @jp310 Thanks, i added `if(n[0])` which might be most simple way

Answer (score 0):

simpler way without checking for 'undefined'

`if(!n[0]){  }`